# How to get boolean values from lambda in python?

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to feed values into lambda and if values exceed a certain limit consecutively 5 times I want to return 1 from the function, I am using filter but each time the `if` statement executes. How should I implement it using lambda? Please any other suggestion.

```
rpm = [45,20,30,50,52,35,55,65]
rpm_limit=45

def check():
    x, i = 0, 0 
    while i < len(rpm):
        if (filter(lambda x: x > rpm_limit, rpm)): # rpm values will be feeded continuously
            x=x+1
            print("RPM: ",rpm[i])
            if x >= 5:
                return 1
            else:
                x=0
        i += 1
    return 0    

print(check())
```

Comment: What? Why do you want a `lambda`? What exactly do you expect your `if filter(..):` to do? Note, in Python 3, `if filter(...):` will *always be considered true*. Also, `filter` will not affect the list you pass to it.

Comment: I need a lambda in order to retrieve a value one by one, it's just necessity I have to build it around lambda. I know I can store the values from filter as a list but then it won't be possible to check consecutive values are greater are not.

Comment: Why is it a necessity? Again, *what are you trying to do here*? It is not clear to me.

Comment: I have been instructed to build it using lambda. I have to check rpm values as they are feeded and if consecutive 5 values are greater I have to return 1

Comment: Why do you have to use `lambda`? Why `filter`? It seems to me you just need to check if consecutive values are greater than whatever.

Comment: Yeah it will easy that way but I don't know instructions are so, Can it be done using lambda? Without storing them

Comment: Your criteria is not clear at all. "Use a lambda" is very, very vague (and a very strange requiremnt... this sounds like *bad* homework).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dead set on using a lambda expression, I think `reduce` is better suited to your purposes.

```
def check():
    max_consec = reduce(lambda acc, r: acc + 1 if r > rpm_limit else 0, rpm, 0)
    return 1 if max_consec >= 5 else 0
```

Here's what's going on: `acc` gets incremented every time an rpm exceeds the max and set to 0 whenever it doesn't. This gives us the longest streak of over-the-max rpms, which we use to decide if we return a 1 or a 0.

[demo](https://repl.it/JMC0/1)

EDIT: for python 3, you'll need to import `reduce` from `functools`. See demo for example.

EDIT2: Corrected some faulty logic. In this new example, `acc` will contiune to be incremented if the max streak length has been met, so the end predicate is true whenever the max streak length has been exceeded. See demo link above for live example.

```
def check():
    max_consec = reduce(
      lambda acc, r: acc + 1 if (r > rpm_limit or acc >= max_streak) else 0, rpm, 0)
    return 1 if max_consec >= max_streak else 0
```

Comment: Yes that's what I needed thanks for the solution I was stuck from long time. I  was trying `reduce` but not in this way.

Comment: Wait, actually this is wrong. The accumulator will be reset if a low rpm appears at the end of the list. Give me a minute to rethink.

Comment: Posted an edit with the corrected logic. [Demo link](https://repl.it/JMC0/1) has also been updated.

Comment: It won't matter cause after getting 5 exceeding values the signal will already been sent to shut down as returning 1. So, the function would be called again.
Can you please explain what 0 at last in the `reduce` statement is doing? 
We are feeding value by using rpm but what the 0 at last is for?

Comment: And one more question if I also have to include another parameter vibration for comaprison in `if` statement how would it be included?

Comment: I can't answer that w/o knowing how you want to factor vibration into the check or how vibrations fit into your data structure.

Comment: Similarly it will just be if(r > rpm_limit and v > vibration_limit) where v will also be feeded as rpm is being, can map be used in such case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148251/discussion-between-wilusdaman-and-prashant-shubham).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that what you want ? Without filter and lambda, you could create a new list of 0/1 (1 if the limit is exceeded). After that you simply need to sum it up:

```
rpm = [45,20,30,50,52,35,55,65]
rpm_limit=45

def check():
    exceedLimit = [1 if x > rpm_limit else 0 for x in rpm] 
    return sum(exceedLimit)

print('RPM exceeded the limit %s times' % check())
```

Returns:

```
RPM exceeded the limit 4 times
```

Comment: No if the rpm limit is exceeded 5 times consecutively, then only it should stop.